# Must I log in upon connecting to a computer via VNC?

Tags: macos, remote-desktop

Can I turn off logging into a computer after connecting via VNC if I have a password set for connecting to the VNC server itself? will I need to enter a password somewhere before connecting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.

Basically VNC works by displaying a login session on your remote computer so if you don't allow **any** logins to the computer it has nothing to display.